# Phoenix: API integration tests vs controller tests

Tags: elixir, integration-testing, phoenix-framework

I have an endpoint for signing in users. I wrote both integration tests and controller tests but they look awfully similar, with the exception that I have more edge cases tested in the controller test (e.g. the user tries to log in with an incorrect email). The contents of the test don't really seem to differ, so it would be great if someone could shed some light on how they should be different.

integration test:

```
defmodule SigningInUserTest do
  use ParrotApi.ConnCase
  alias ParrotApi.Router

  @opts Router.init([])
  describe "POST api/v1/sessions" do
    test "success" do
      email = "eric@spaghetti.com"
      password = "ilovemodals"
      user = insert(:user,
                    email: email,
                    password_hash: Comeonin.Bcrypt.hashpwsalt(password))
      user_params = %{
        user: %{
          email: user.email,
          password: password,
        }
      }

      conn = build_conn(:post, "/api/v1/sessions", user_params)
      response = Router.call(conn, @opts)
      assert response.status == 201
    end

    test "failure" do
      email = "eric@spaghetti.com"
      password = "ilovemodalszzz"
      user = insert(:user,
                    email: email,
                    password_hash: Comeonin.Bcrypt.hashpwsalt(password))
      user_params = %{
        user: %{
          email: user.email,
          password: "bad_password",
        }
      }

      conn = build_conn(:post, "/api/v1/sessions", user_params)
      response = Router.call(conn, @opts)
      assert response.status == 401
    end
  end
```

controller test:

```
defmodule ParrotApi.SessionControllerTest do
  use ParrotApi.ConnCase

  setup %{conn: conn} do
    {:ok, conn: put_req_header(conn, "accept", "application/json")}
  end

  describe "#create" do
    test "returns the user when the email and password match", %{conn: conn} do
      email = "eric@spaghetti.com"
      password = "ilovemodals"
      user = insert(:user,
                    email: email,
                    password_hash: Comeonin.Bcrypt.hashpwsalt(password))
      rsvp = insert(:rsvp, user: user)
      user_params = %{
        user: %{
          email: email,
          password: password,
        }
      }
      conn = conn
             |> post(session_path(conn, :create), user_params)
      assert json_response(conn, 201)["data"] == %{
        "id" => user.id,
        "email" => user.email,
        "name" => user.name,
        "interests" => user.interests,
        "location" => user.location,
        "image_url" => user.image_url,
        "is_admin" => user.is_admin,
        "rsvps" => [rsvp.meetup_id],
      }
    end


    test "returns an error when the email and password don't match", %{conn: conn} do
      email = "eric@spaghetti.com"
      password = "ilovemodals"
      insert(:user,
             email: email,
             password_hash: Comeonin.Bcrypt.hashpwsalt(password))
      user_params = %{
        user: %{
          email: email,
          password: "bad_password",
        }
      }
      conn = conn
             |> post(session_path(conn, :create), user_params)
      assert json_response(conn, 401) == %{
        "message" => "The email and password you entered did not match our records. Please try again."
      }
    end

    test "returns an error when the user doesn't exist", %{conn: conn} do
      user_params = %{
        user: %{
          email: "eric@spaghetti.com",
          password: "bad_password",
        }
      }
      conn = conn
             |> post(session_path(conn, :create), user_params)
      assert json_response(conn, 401) == %{
        "message" => "The email and password you entered did not match our records. Please try again."
      }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Your integration tests don't appear to be testing anything that your controller tests are already covering. But then, I believe you already know this.

What your controller tests aren't covering is the path through the web server. I would suggest enabling the server for your integration tests and use a http client like `HttpPoison` to do real requests.

I would also suggest that you tag these tests as integration tests. If you find they are slowing down your tests, then disable them by default. We use `hound` for ExAdmin integration tests we doing real browser fills and clicks. These tests are disabled by default. To do this:

```
# my_app/config/test.exs
use Mix.Config
config :my_app, TestMyApp.Endpoint,
  http: [port: 4001],
  server: true

# my_app/test/test_helpers.exs
ExUnit.configure(exclude: [pending: true, integration: true])
ExUnit.start()
```

And then run them with:

```
# Run all tests
mix test --include integration
# or run only integration
mix test --only integration
```